# How to use Hikvision IP camera for image processing using Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, face-recognition, ip-camera, hikvision

I am using **HIKVISION IP camera (DS-2CD204WFWD-I) & (DS-2CD214WFWD-I)** with NVR for image processing (face recognition) using OpenCV and python.

currently, in-camera setting, I have selected 20fps whereas when I run my code I am getting frames at very slow speed like 1 frame after 5 seconds.
so do I need to keep connected it with NVR or I have to directly use It's IP address for image processing?
For face recognition, I am using Microsoft cognitive services (Face API).

Answer (score 1):

this is my problem too. the only solution I found is too pass your process to GPU
if there is no process or low process performance is as same as the input. u can try OpenCL or CUDA if your GPU is Nvidia.
take a look at this link: https://www.learnopencv.com/getting-started-opencv-cuda-modul/